# Como tornar legível o código que usa propriedades da String?

Tags: java, string

Tenho uma string que usa partes de outra String, como tornar mais "limpo" esse código? Visto que é bem dificil compreender.

```
String sessionHash = dirPath.substring(dirPath.substring(0, dirPath.length() - 1).lastIndexOf("/"));
```

> sessionHash: /23980dc32e16792007de3343f1f99211/
>
> dirPath:
>   /home/daniela/oknok/data/uploads/23980dc32e16792007de3343f1f99211/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pelo que entendi acho que o método [`getname()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName()) produz o resultado que você espera:

```
String sessionHash = new File(dirPath).getName();
```

Ou para ficar igualzinho:

```
String sessionHash = "/" + new File(dirPath).getName() + "/";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/g0jrcq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aighnpam-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/GetPath.java).

Comment: +1 e se ela quiser as barras em volta (tal como no exemplo) é só adicioná-las via concatenação de string.

Comment: @mgibsonbr mudei para resolver isto embora eu duvide que seja a intenção manter as barras. Eu estava fazendo igual a sua mas abortei porque achei que não melhorava quase nada.

Comment: Tirando o `substring` duplo, não melhora muita coisa mesmo... Você saberia dizer se esse método proposto, usando o `File`, vai dar um resultado igual num sistema Windows? (que usa "\" em vez de "/" como separador) Eu acho que vai, mas estou sem compilador aqui pra testar...

Comment: a intenção era manter as barras, obrigada. Realmente bem mais legível e de fácil manutenção.

Comment: @mgibsonbr até onde eu sei vai dar certo, mas também não posso garantir.

Comment: Se eu não me engano, existe uma constante na classe `File`, a `FileSeparator`, que é melhor pra isso. Usando o valor da resposta fica um pouco preso ao SO para execução do código.

Comment: @mutlei Concordo mas neste caso não vai gerar um nome de arquivo e sim uma *string* que a autora só onde vai usar. Pelo que entendi precisa ser assim mesmo independente do OS, portanto neste caso específico não deve ser usado o `separator`. A não ser que ela diga que tem que ser diferente, aí fica seu registro que precisa adaptar isto.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso através do método [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29): ele quebra uma string em pedaços usando uma expressão regular como delimitadora. Quebrando em torno da barra, e pegando o penúltimo pedaço (o último é vazio, pois está depois da última barra) você consegue o resultado que quer:

```
String[] partes = dirPath.split("/");
String sessionHash = "/" + partes[partes.length-2] + "/";
```

No caso específico da barra, entretanto, é mais simples usar a classe `File`, tal como [sugerido por Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54737/215).